# What is the meaning of ドリフ in this sentence

Tags: words

> 「考えてもみなさいよ。**ドリフでも**いつも決まって怒られるのはカトちゃんでしょ」
>    Try to think about it. The one who always, without fail, gets scolded is カトちゃん. Right?

I haven't the faintest idea what ドリフでも means in this sentence. I can only guess that ドリフ is a person's name and I have completely mangled the translation. If it is a name though, I can't come up with a translation that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, there's [a Japanese band called "The Drifters" (ザ・ドリフターズ)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BB%E3%83%89%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA), often abbreviated ドリフ, one of whose members is [a fellow named Kato Cha](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A0%E8%97%A4%E8%8C%B6), who is sometimes called カトちゃん.

Comment: これ回答したら歳バレてまうやん！平成生まれで通ってるのに・・

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a name rather than the language. Thanks to senshin for answer I needed.